# Add website in the bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I try to use the following code. It works. But the true address is   `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential`. So if I use `Matrix_exponential`, it does not work.

```
 myref.bib   
    @misc{ exp,
       author = "Wikipedia",
       title = "Matrix exponential",
       year = "2014",
       url = "\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrixexponential}",
       note = "[Online; accessed 12-May-2014]"
     }
```

my.tex

```
    \bibliographystyle{alphadin} 
    \bibliography{myref}
```

Comment: Try `Matrix\_exponential`.  Otherwise, please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)),

Comment: @jon - "Escaping" the underscore character in the URL string is not as good as omitting the `\url` directive from the field named `url`.

Comment: @Mico -- Doubtlessly true.  I usually don't bother trying a real test unless there's a some attempt to provide a MWE and/or unless it happens to be a topic I am personally interested in.  (Selfish/lazy/etc., I know.  But I am a good upvoter of others who do...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `alphadin` bibliography style and its "sibling" style files `abbrvdin`, `natdin`, `plaindin`, and `unsrtdin` are set up to handle fields named `url` directly, by encasing its contents automatically in a `\url{...}` directive. You should therefore *not* encase the contents of a `url` field in a `\url{...}` macro of your own.

Do be sure, though, to load the `url` and/or the `hyperref` package. This will ensure that `\url` directives are processed correctly and that long URL strings are broken up across lines. To quote from the bst file:

> %%  Die Darstellung von Internetadressen wird durch das Zusatzpaket url.sty  ver 3.1, 15-Mar-2004 von Donald Arseneau erheblich verbessert und  wird sehr empfohlen.
>
> %%  HYPERREF-Paket: wird dieses Paket zusaetzlich geladen, werden im output aktivierbare externe (URLs usw.) und interne (Dokumentbezogene) Links gesetzt.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myref.bib}   % write contents of this env. to "myref.bib"
@misc{ exp,
   author = "Wikipedia",
   title  = "Matrix exponential",
   year   = "2014",
   url    = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential",
   note   = "[Online; accessed 12-May-2014]"
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % optional
\bibliographystyle{alphadin} 
\begin{document}
\cite{exp}
\bibliography{myref}
\end{document}
```